# How to deploy ng2 app after ng-build

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

I've never understood what comes after the `ng build` command. I mean, how can you actually load your built app on a normal server and access it? Until now I've found only topics talking about the `ng serve` and `ng build`, saying that after the `ng build` you're done. But that's not true.

If I try to build and then navigate to the folder, I get a lot of errors in the console about files not found etc... not to mention errors about unmatched routes and so on.

The fact is that the app before the build using `ng serve` works like a charm, but I can't go to the client and say: 
*"Well, you have to use ng serve".*

Jokes apart, how do I actually serve my built app without using GitHub pages and other hosts, but using my own server?

I swear that I've searched a lot on this topic, but I've never found a "stable" solution for it.

Thanks for any possible tip. I'm freaking out with this thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Angular CLI: ng build
Navigate to your app folder /dist

[image]

If you want to run it on your PC with no hassle just download USB Webserver and just copy the files to the root folder and run the server, you can port it to your client via usb or on client PC.

To run the app on a server: copy everything from dist folder + all your assets ( bootstrap.css or image folder or fonts folder)

[image]

http://162.244.83.64/

===========================================

If you are trying to run the app from local PC keep in mind that the app is looking for your assets in the root folder (C:/, D:/).

Open your Index.html file and edit the   to point to the correct path, you don't need to do this on a server or hosting.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but how can I do if I have external assets like svg icons in their own asset folders? When I use them in the css it fail finding them... And I also get route unmatched error when accessing the dist folder...

Comment: If  i try to run it from my PC directly I will get path errors because if run it from c:/something/something  and it is searching for files in c:/ root

Comment: As soon as I get back home I'll try. I'm having a doubt about that base href. I think I've missed it out

Comment: I just finished doing this:

Comment: Made a cloud server, installed apache2, copy all the files from dist to /var/www/html  and everything works as intended. http://162.244.83.64/

Comment: Just saw it, it works. I'll give you a confirmation of mine soon. Thanks for helping for now. Can you share the zip somewhere?

Comment: Worked like a charm. It was only a paths related problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Because of new `<base href="/">` attribute in the html, app is looking for your assets in the respective root folder.

So try to remove and run so that it will work and load the `base href` in run time.

You can use the below code to get it working

```
import {APP_BASE_HREF} from '@angular/common';
{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue : '/' }
```

or using javascript

```
document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
```